# Python semi-complex formula not working (always prints the same thing)

Tags: printing

```
answer = input(str(num1) + operation + str(num2) + "=")  

    if (answer != add(num1, num2) and answer != sub(num1, num2) and answer != div(num1, num2) and answer != tim(num1, num2)):
        print ("Wrong")
    else:
        print ("Correct!")
```

I've done a very simple maths quiz but there is one bit thats not working. "Wrong" is always printed even if the answer is corect. The worst thing is that i couldnt find the mistake for the last 30mins.

```
    if (operation == "+"):
    print(add(num1, num2))
elif(operation == "-"):
    print(sub(num1, num2))
elif(operation == "/"):
    print(div(num1, num2))
elif(operation == "*"):
    print(tim(num1, num2))

def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2
def tim(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2
def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2
```

anything wrong with this?

Comment: Check the return type of add, sub, div and tim methods. 1 is not equal "1". And you are using "AND" , so the answer must be equal to add and sub and  div and tim all the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code myself, and my code gives me back "Correct!" when I input the correct answer. This probably means that the problem lies in one of your other functions, which aren't shown: add, sub, div, or tim. I don't know how you defined these functions. Can you show us these functions as well as the rest of your program?

Another concern I have is that your program, even when working as intended, will sometimes print "Correct!" when the answer is not correct. For example, let's say the math problem is

> 2+2=

If the user inputs 1, which is clearly incorrect, your program would still print "Correct!" because div(2,2) returns 1. This does not satisfy your first if statement and executes the else statement.